# How to play audiofiles with Clip more fluidly while succesively pressing JButton

Tags: java, audio, playback, clip

I am teaching myself java since a year and for now I am trying to create a Sampler Device. This is my second java project and I got stuck in figuring out how to playback audiofiles fluidly while succesively hitting JButton. The audiosample starts at the beginning everytime i hit the Jbutton which is working fine till the sample is shortly before end. So before the clip is finished I`m hitting JButton, to start the playback at the beginning, but it doesn`t work and after the clip ends I press JButton and it works normal again. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

class Drumthread extends JFrame implements ActionListener, LineListener {

```
JButton button1;
AudioFormat format;
Clip clip;

File audio1 = new File (samplefile);    

Drumthread() {

AudioInputStream stream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audio1);
format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);

DataLine.Info clipinfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(clipinfo);
clip.open(stream1);
clip.addLineListener(this);


button1 = new JButton("1");
add(button1);
button1.addActionListener(this);


setVisible(true);

}

public void update(LineEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP  && event.getLine().equals(clip)) {
        clip.stop();
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
    }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String play = evt.getActionCommand();

    if(play == "1") {
        clip.start();
    }
    if(play == "1" && clip.isRunning()){
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
    }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to venture a guess. The breakout of the `if` statements in your `actionPerformed` seems suspicious to me.

Consider the following scenario: the clip is playing and near the end of the playback.

In this case, the first `if` condition will be true and the `start` method will execute. This will do nothing. From the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#start()): "If invoked on a line that is already running, this method does nothing."

Then the second `if` statement executes. When the clip is near its end, the clip may finish playing between the time of the `if` condition test and the time when `setFramePosition` executes. The situation could be viewed as a "race condition," a common hazard for multi-threaded coding. In this case the two concurrently running threads are the one doing the testing and the one executing the playback on the clip.

If the race is "won" by the playback thread, then the playback will end before the clip's position is reset to 0, and the clip will end up stopped a 0.

I suggest having the `actionPerformed` method stop the playback, move the position and restart *every* time the button is hit, regardless of the state of the clip.

Another suggestion on your code, the `update` condition of your `LineListener` tests and executes only if the clip has stopped. So, giving the clip a `stop` method should be redundant.

A little editorializing on my part: Java's `javax.sound.sampled` library gives us access to powerful, low latency audio coding. I've had a lot of satisfaction and success with it, and personally think Java is underrated as a tool for audio projects. (Most prefer C++.) I hope you have some fun with it as well!

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for your help I really appreciate it. I added some changes now to my code, here s what I did: I removed the LineListener completely and made also use of the clip.stop method in the actionPerformed section, and it works much better than before now. I can hit the JButtons as fast as I want and my samples are getting fired everytime. But unfortunately the problem while playback at the end of my samples still exist. I tried almost everything with the coding knowledge I have but maybe Im fundamentely wrong in solving a problem like this with simple if else statements. This is what i changed:

```
if(play == "1") {
        clip.stop();
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();

    }
    if(play == "1" && clip.isRunning()){
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
    }
```